# Something strange that I saw in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

```
   typedef struct stage_tag {
   pthread_mutex_t     mutex;          /* Protect data */
    pthread_cond_t      avail;          /* Data available */
   pthread_cond_t      ready;          /* Ready for data */
   int                 data_ready;     /* Data present */
   long                data;           /* Data to process */
    pthread_t           thread;         /* Thread for stage */
   struct stage_tag    *next;          /* Next stage */
  } stage_t;

 typedef struct pipe_tag {
  pthread_mutex_t     mutex;          /* Mutex to protect pipe */
  stage_t             *head;          /* First stage */
  stage_t             *tail;          /* Final stage */
  int                 stages;         /* Number of stages */
  int                 active;         /* Active data elements */
```

} pipe_t;

```
  int pipe_create (pipe_t *pipe, int stages)
{
int pipe_index;
stage_t **link = &pipe->head, *new_stage, *stage;
int status;
```

.....
//  The question lies in the method pipe_create. There is a double pointer of type stage_t which has three values... What kind of declaration is this? I am really confused.

Comment: Three values? No, just three variable declarations. You end up with link, new_stage and stage.

Comment: No, it doesn't "have three values", rather, those are three separate declarations.

Answer (score 2):

A single declaration statement can declare multiple variables whose type are related (in the sense that they differ only by qualification):

```
T **x, *y, z;
```

is the same as:

```
T **x;
T *y;
T z;
```

A slightly absurd example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 1, * const b = &a, * const * c = &b;
    return a + *b + **c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating three different variables. one is `stage_t **` type `link` variable and initializing it to &pipe->head. Second is `stage_t *` type `new_stage` variable and third is `stage_t *` type `stage` variable. Last two variables are uninitialized.